# Printing the bibliography heading in uppercase but showing it as sentence case in the ToC

Tags: bibliographies, table-of-contents, capitalization

At my class I am supposed to write a report where the chapter headings are always in uppercase, but have to printed in sentence case in the table of contents. For regular chapters I have achieved this by using

```
\chapter*{EXAMPLE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Example}
```

but I cannot figure out how to achieve the same result for the bibliography. I have used

```
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

but then the bibliography heading is printed twice in the table of contents. Is there any way to force the table of contents to print the references heading once?

Here is the preamble for the document

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{times}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the standard classes the bibliography is not automatically added to the table of contents, so you should at least provide information about the class you're using and relevant parts of the preamble.

Comment: I am using the report class for my document so the bibliography is added automatically to the toc.

Comment: No, the report class *doesn't* do that; so the addition is due to some package you're loading.

Comment: I believe that a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would make your situation and desires clear.

Comment: Here is the preamble for the document

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

% Packages
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{times}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your code, but call

```
\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}
```

Remember, though, to issue

```
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

in order to be sure that the page reference is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The package `apacite` provides their own bibliography environment. Therefore, the package offers some options. Related to your questions the important options are:

- `tocbib`
- `notocbib`

The manual explains:

> `tocbib`
>
> This puts the bibliography in the table of contents, even if it is
>   unnumbered, provided of course that a table of contents is requested
>   in the document (by `\tableofcontents`). This is the default.
>
> `notocbib`
>
> This does not put the bibliography in the table of contents if it is
>   an unnumbered section or chapter. If it’s numbered, it is always in
>   the table of contents.

So you have to set the option `notocbib`.