# How to have headings not capitalized using `tocbibind`?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, header-footer, koma-script, capitalization

I have a problem with my bibliography: with my settings, by default the bibliography does not appear in the table of contents (toc). So I included `\usepackage{tocbibind}` into my preamble which solved this problem, but caused another problem: with the `\documentclass{scrbook}`, on top of each page it is written, to which chapter or section the current page belongs to. After using `tocbibind`, this heading (?) (I don't know the technical term for this) is always capitalized ("BIBLIOGRAPHY"), but I want it to be "Bibliography" (which was given before `tocbibind` was included). The title of the bibliography at page 7 in the MWE below is "Bibliography", but at page 8 it is "BIBLIOGRAPHY" (see picture below).

[image: page 8]

Somehow it is the opposite of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43602/printing-the-bibliography-heading-in-uppercase-but-showing-it-as-sentence-case-i), I want it to be sentence case everywhere: in the toc, at the start of the bibliography, at the headings of each page.

Using the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52412/105520), my MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {\blindtext[5]},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The first chapter}
\section{First Section}

\blindtext[10]
\section{Second Section}
\blindtext[5]
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your MWE and the use, or not, of `tocbibind` had no effect on the appearance of the Bibliography page. It did effect whether or not the Bibliography was listed in the ToC.

Comment: @PeterWilson The heading on page 8 should change. The "Bibliography" title on page 7 remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove package `tocbibind` and use KOMA-Script option `bibliography=totoc`:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {\blindtext[5]},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The first chapter}
\section{First Section}

\blindtext[10]
\section{Second Section}
\blindtext[5]
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If the ToC should also get a ToC entry, then add

```
\setup{toc}{totoc}
```

to the preamble.