# Make chapter, references, appendix names in TOC uppercase without patch or macro. Document class - Book

Tags: tocloft, styles, uppercase

I need my chapter names displayed as uppercase in my TOC. I am quite new to Latex and I am not comfortable using patches or macros as explained in this solution [Uppercase sections and subsections on ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113681/uppercase-sections-and-subsections-on-toc?rq=1) and this solution [Upper case chapter titles Tocstyle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160982/upper-case-chapter-titles-tocstyle).

Therefore, I would like to ask if there is a simpler way to make chapter titles uppercase in the TOC, maybe using the `tocloft` package?

I have also picked up that the `hyperref` package causes some problems. Please note that I do use this package in my main document and I have also loaded it in my very simple MWE (although not used it specifically).

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %help make sfdefault arial
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[auto]{chappg} %want to have page numbering per section this also works on equation numbering
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc} 

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{first section}

\clearpage

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
After trying the solution by @fran, I realized my initial question was incomplete. I also need to make the references and the appendix headings uppercase in the TOC. It seems like the reverse was achieved here with [Printing the bibliography heading in uppercase but showing it as sentence case in the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43602/printing-the-bibliography-heading-in-uppercase-but-showing-it-as-sentence-case-i) but my document gives an error for the `apacite` environment. I have included an updated MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %help make sfdefault arial
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[auto]{chappg} %want to have page numbering per section this also works on equation numbering
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} %want to display "appendix" before A,B,C etc. Use [title]
 
\usepackage[maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=authoryear,
  bibstyle=authoryear,
  sorting=nyt, %sort by name title year
  natbib=true,
  giveninits=true,
  hyperref
  ]{biblatex} % CustomBib
  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{2000_adams_prob,
  title={Urban stormwater management planning with analytical probabilistic models},
  author={Adams, Barry J},
  year={2000},
  publisher={John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York, NY (US)}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{bychapter}

\chapter[CHAPS CHAPTER 2]{First chapter}
\section{first section}

\clearpage

\chapter[CHAPS CHAPTER 2]{Second chapter}
blabla bla \citep{2000_adams_prob}

\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title={References}]

\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}} %don't want to show the appendix page number in the Toc
\chapter[CHAPS FIRST APPENDIX]{First appendix} 

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hopefully `tocloft` will soon be updated to cater for this.

Comment: `\chapter[TRY THIS]{Try this}`

Comment: Thanks @Fran ,  Giving it a go - I see that I will need to have another work around for the References and the Appendixes (will update my MWE to include a Appendix and a Referance), I will give it another day or two to see if there are some other ingenious answers, otherwise I might read -up on patching a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
 % small page, just for the screenshot
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=9cm,margin=1cm,tmargin=-2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[auto]{chappg} %want to have page numbering per section this also works on equation numbering
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} %want to display "appendix" before A,B,C etc. Use [title]
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{APPENDICES}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true ]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{2000adams,
  title={Urban stormwater management planning with analytical probabilistic models},
  author={Adams, Barry J},
  year={2000},
  publisher={John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York, NY (US)}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\def\mychapter#1{\chapter[\MakeUppercase{#1}]{#1}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\MakeUppercase\relax}
\defbibheading{xxx}[References]{\chapter*{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\markboth{REFERENCES (twoside header)}{REFERENCES (oneside header)}}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\mychapter{First chapter}
\section{first section}\lipsum[1][1-2]
\mychapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[2][1-2] \citep{2000adams}. \lipsum[3][1] 
\printbibliography[heading=xxx]
% \newpage More bib ....\newpage Even more bib ... % just to test headers 
\appendix\addappheadtotoc
\mychapter{First appendix} \lipsum[3][1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply an all the trouble @Fran ,Seems like I will need a bit of coding after all. So, basically you propose a new chapter style `\mychapter`, that change entries in the ToC to uppercase without affecting the document style, for the references we will use the `\defbibheading` command to force the chapter style. Last question, I need the word “Appendix” before my Appendix number, that is why I have specified the `\begin{appendices}` , `\end{appendices}` environment with `\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}` , any idea how to capitalize the word “Appendix” in the ToC as well